# Springboot Hibernate One to Many infinty recursion

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, set, spring-data

I have two SQL tables as follow:

**users**
id
username
password
...and more irrelevant stuff

**activities**
id
name
description
users

I created two entities classes with their Repository (with the anotation @RepositoryRestResource)

```
@Entity
public class Users {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "users")
    private Set<Activities> activities;

    public Set<Activities> getActivities() {
        return activities;
    }

//constructors && getters setters
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Activities {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "users")
    private Users users;

    private String name;

    private String description;

//constructors && get
```

I created an endpoint to test the workflow, by creating an activity. It's all hardcoded as follow

```
 @RequestMapping("/calendar")
    public Set<Activities> goToCalendar(Authentication authentication){
        Users user = unbreakableService.isAuth(authentication);
        Activities activities = new Activities(user,"karate", "entrenobueno");
        activitiesRespository.save(activities);
        return usersRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername()).getActivities();
    }
```

The code is saving the activity correctly, but, when it's supposed to return the list of activities, it returns an infinity recursive information, like:

```
[{"id":161,"users":{"id":121,"username":"Ojka","password":"$2a$10$Z/bj.5JvQmPquJ67fqF.leUyBkkXJ/2x3z/.bUon8YsIAdV8HMnoG","email":"ojka","pushup":99999,"pullup":null,"handstandhold":9999,"handstandpushup":null,"frontlever":null,"backlever":null,"activities":[{"id":161,"users":{"id":121,"username":"Ojka","password":"$2a$10$Z/bj.5JvQmPquJ67fqF.leUyBkkXJ/2x3z/.bUon8YsIAdV8HMnoG","email":"ojka","pushup":99999,"pullup":null,"handstandhold":9999,"handstandpushup":null,"frontlever":null,"backlever":null,"activities":[{"id":161,"users":{"id":121,"username":"Ojka","password":"$2a$10$Z/bj.5JvQmPquJ67fqF.leUyBkkXJ/2x3z/.bUon8YsIAdV8HMnoG","email":"ojka","pushup":99999,"pullup":null,"handstandhold":9999,"handstandpushup":null,"frontlever":null,"backlever":null,"activities":[{"id":161,"users":{"id":121,"username":"Ojka","password":"$2a$10$Z/bj.5JvQmPquJ67fqF.leUyBkkXJ/2x3z/.bUon8YsIAdV8HMnoG","email":"ojka","pushup":99999,"pullup":null,"handstandhold":9999,"handstandpushup":null,"frontl
```

I can't read the whole log since the console doesn't show that much information.
This is the first error I can see

```
 Failure while trying to resolve exception [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed.
```

And this is the last line of the log

```
2020-01-25 20:48:54.795 ERROR 19924 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.e.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$StaticView : Cannot render error page for request [/api/calendar] and exception [Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: com.unbreakable.unbreakable.persistance.Users["activities"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet[0]->com.unbreakable.unbreakable.persistance.Activities["users"]->com.unbreakable.unbreakable.persistance.Users["activities"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.Persi....
```

If I check the table activities (SELECT * FROM ACTIVITIES) there's no infinity information. Just a few activities (the ones I created testing it).

I believe, it should return a Set of activities that the user has.

Comment: BTW the getter from getActivities() if as follows:

    public Set<Activities> getActivities() {
        return activities;
    }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can suppress the output in json in a couple of ways:

1. You can use `@JsonIgnore` over the field with the relationship (`activities` or `users`).
2. If you want to generate the json with the parent but not with the children, you can annotate `users` with `@JsonBackReference` and `activities` with `@JsonManagedReference`